# Is it possible to put the value of a config/setting in the VSCode titlebar?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

I want to put a conditional value in the vscode window title, I wanted to output whether I am currently in VIM mode.

My plan was to try something like this, but it doesn't work:

`${config:vim.disableExtension ? "" : "(VIM)"}`

Are config variables supported in the window title?

Comment: What are you using to change your title? Please post the code or name of extension you're using.

Comment: I'm using the built-in feature (in settings) that allows to customize the window title

Comment: Could you please tell me your purpose for this question? Why do you want to put Vim state in the title bar?

Comment: @wlisrausr - i'm using something that inputs text into vscode, it uses vim keys, but I sometimes turn vim off. I want this tool to know if vscode is in vim mode.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

For the latest version of Visual Studio Code now (1.38.1), those are the only options available to control the window title. I think you can't use the extension config value to dynamically change the window title. Maybe you can propose this functionality through VS Code GitHub issue. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just some sort of eccentricity Madd0g appears to display; it's more than that. The key to that request is [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). See, AHK is both a Windows end-user program and a fully-fledged programming language; on the user-side of AHK, one of the things it does is [hotstrings](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm): a piece of user-defined abbreviations that, when typed, they expand, like `inctb` -> `I need to change the title bar`. AHK, while running in the background, monitors the user input until it sees a pattern which was predefined as an abbreviation. When the sequence is typed, the program hits `Backspace` the number of times equal to the lenght of the abbreviation then types the expansion for you. So upon typing “inctb”, the program will hit Backspace 5 times, then write out “I need to change the title bar”. Pretty cool, right? There are dozens of programs which do that, both free and paid. The underrated AutoHotkey is both free, open source and the most powerful.

But there is the catch: AHK doesn't know if the user means to actually type (INSERT MODE) text, or if he's performing a sequence of Vim commands (COMMAND MODE). So when a user defines a hotstring like this: `50x` -> `Fifty times`, if VS Code is accidentally with Vim set to command mode, it will perform the disastrous “erase fifty characters ahead" command instead of typing the phrase "Fifty times". So the performance boost the user intended to have with Vim will be neutralized by AutoHotkey's, or vice-versa.

**“OK, now I know what AHK is capable of doing but I don't know changing the titlebar would be of any help”**. Thing is, among a million other functions, AHK [can watch](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) `the active window's title`, and have a hotstring or hotkey be enabled only if the active window's title matches a predefined string. So we write our AutoHotkey script like this:

```
#IfWinActive, .* - Visual Studio Code - Insert mode

::mhs::my hotstring

#IfWinActive
```

The part enclosed by the "#IfWin... fences are only executed when the active window title matches that pattern (something followed by “Visual Studio Code” followed by “- Insert mode”.

That way, we would be able to have AutoHotkey do the hotstring expansions **only if it detects** that current window (VS Code's) has a piece of text matching "- Insert mode". Then we would have the best of the two worlds without a conflict.

See? It's actually very important for people serious about productivity, which is something VS Code, Vim and AutoHotkey have in common. :)

But how can I possibly expect this to be implemented via a feature request? [I already did that; no one seemed to care](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/6421) :( This seems so fringe by whoever looks at it. Except it would have a ton of other uses, because it would also monitor the behaviour of any plugin, which could come up handy.